# Multiple lights dimming using single TRIAC zero detcetion module

Tags: microcontroller, pwm, light, triac, home-automation

We know well we can dim single lights using single TRIAC module with the help of PWM signals from controller. My question is, I want to control the lights which are placed on hall. Let us consider 15-20 bulbs.

1. Is it possible to control single PWM signal and single TRAIC module?
2. We need to consider only current value of TRIAC module?
3. What are all the hardware points should be consider at the time of automate.
4. Which micro-controller is best for home automation?
5. Is it possible to ON/OFF lights using TRIAC module? If its not how to do that?

Comment: how big is this hall? are all the lights on the same phase? what type of lamp are they?

Comment: What type of lights and surge rating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Is it possible to control single PWM signal and single TRAIC module?

[image]

*Figure 1. TRIAC dimming uses phase-angle control.*

Yes, but we use phase angle control, not PWM.

> 2. We need to consider only current value of TRIAC module?

It is unclear what you are asking.

> 3. What are all the hardware points should be consider at the time of automate.

You write the user requirements, not us.

> 4. Which micro-controller is best for home automation?

This is impossible to answer as you have no requirements.

> 5. Is it possible to ON/OFF lights using TRIAC module?

Yes. Zero trigger delay will give full power. No trigger will give zero power.

Comment: 2)For the second question,I am asking to you like if we want to control more lights using single channel TRAIC module,we need to purchase module which contains high current rate?

Comment: 5)I know well when sine peaks are crossing zero,we will trigger pulse using opto -coupler   ,it will open the SCR,so load will get power.So when no trigger bulb will always OFF ? right

Comment: My questions using if I am going to use normal 2A,peak 5A TRAIC module,how many no of bulb we can dim? when load is more we need to consider the current rating or not.It means we need to choose nay high current TRIAC module depends up on the load

Comment: 2) Yes, of course the TRIAC (not "TRAIC") rating must be >= load current. I would go at least >= 2 x load current. Note that filament lamps inrush current can be 10 > warm current. 5) No trigger, no current. "*... how many no of bulb we can dim?*" How could I know? You haven't given a specification for the bulb.